# Efficiently collect logs from Heroku and Archive to S3

Tags: heroku, logging, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of Heroku apps (similar apps deployed on multiple instances to server different customers). Each app generates some logs and I wish to archive the generated logs to S3.

I tried using Heroku addons but after a point, the price of these addon services do not justify my use case.

Therefore, I tried writing a very simple log drain and started converting the log entries into file and publishing the files to S3.

Here's the sample code -

```
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    r = math.floor(random.random() * 10000)

    bucket = 'my-example-bucket'
    key = '/logdrain/raw/{y}/{mon}/{d}/{h}/{h}-{min}-{s}-{ms}-{r}.txt'.format(
        y=now.year, mon=now.month, d=now.day, h=now.hour, min=now.minute, s=now.second, ms=now.microsecond//1000, r=r)

    s3_file_path = 's3://{bucket}/{key}'.format(bucket=bucket, key=key)

    # Append the new content and save the file back to S3
    data = str(request.data)

    if 'l10' in data.lower():
        print('ERROR: ', data)

    with smart_open.open(s3_file_path, 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(data)

    return 'Log write successful', 200
```

But looks like I am unable to match the ingestion rate of logplex with my consumption/processing speed. Here's the logline

```
ERROR:  b'142 <172>1 2019-07-03T10:06:07+00:00 host heroku logplex - Error L10 (output buffer overflow): 6 messages dropped since 2019-07-03T09:43:52+00:00.595 <158>1 2019-07-03T10:06:07.509894+00:00 host heroku router - at=info ...
```

Here's [the doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#l10-drain-buffer-overflow) which confirms the same. Just wanted to know if someone has a better approach in mind to implement the log drain.

PS: I have deployed this on a flask app on Heroku with 2enterprise dynos and still getting the message dropped issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that writing directly to S3 *for every incoming drain request* is never going to be fast enough to avoid an L10 error. I think you need two things:

1. a buffer
2. non-blocking upload to S3

I'd suggest writing to a local file until a) it reaches a certain size, and/or b) a certain amount of time has elapsed. When the file is thus "finished", upload it to S3 without blocking the main (listening) loop. There are many ways to implement non-blocking upload, but the simplest is probably threading.

Because Heroku has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and [cycles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) its dynos, you'll need to **trap** `SIGTERM` and quickly upload whatever you have buffered at that time before the `SIGKILL`.

I'm curious how this works for you as I've been thinking of implementing something similar for my own Heroku apps.